# How to use linq to manage stock level in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, pos

I want to manage the stock level(To reduce the product quantity availability)  in the database once purchases are made. and alert the user when the quantity is less than 2. or have a read-only input box to show the quantity available for each product. my Datacontext includes Products, Sales, Customers, Categories and SalesDetails

In the saleButton I am adding each product to list then sum multiply the quantity and price then get the sum of the product price added to list. which has an ID for each list of purchases

Then in the submit sales button, I want it to process payment and grab the list and save in the db, **then deduct the quantity of each item from stock.** This where the issue is. I am trying to get the stock level and total product using LINQ but I have been getting errors. How do I change stock level after payment is processed?

Thanks

This is "add item" to list of product by a customer

```
    private void SalesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaleId += 1;
            var newDate = date.ToString("F");

            if (AddSalesProductNameComboBox.Text != "" && AddSalesCustomerNameComboBox.Text != "" && 
                ProductSalesPrice.Text != "" && ProductQuantityBought.Text != "")
            {

                var sale = new Sale
                {
                    SalesID = SaleId,
                    ProductName = AddSalesProductNameComboBox.Text,
                    CustomerName = AddSalesCustomerNameComboBox.Text,
                    ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(ProductSalesPrice.Text),
                    QuantityPurchased = Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantityBought.Text),
                    Date =   DateTime.Parse(newDate), 
                    Total = Convert.ToDecimal(ProductSalesPrice.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantityBought.Text)

                };

                posManager.AddSales(sale);

                var NewAmount = posManager.Sales.Sum(c => c.Total);
                AmountDueDisplay.Text = NewAmount.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is submitting sales to DB and processing stock level

```
 private void SubmitSalesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            decimal Balance = 0;
            //Check if inputs are empty
            if (AmountPaidInput.Text != "" && AmountDueDisplay.Text != "")
            {
                //Calculating the Amount due and amouunt paid
                decimal AmtDue = Convert.ToDecimal(AmountDueDisplay.Text);
                decimal AmtPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(AmountPaidInput.Text);
                DisplayBalance.Text = (AmtDue - AmtPaid).ToString();
            }

            //pass the calculated balance to the balance variable  
            Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(DisplayBalance.Text);

            //SaleDetailsID += 1;
            var newSalesDate = date.ToString("F");


            var salesDetails = new SalesDetail
            {
                SalesDetailsID = SaleDetailsID,
                SalesID = SaleId,
                SalesDetailsCustomerName = AddSalesCustomerNameComboBox.Text,
                SalesProductName = AddSalesProductNameComboBox.Text,
                AmountPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(AmountPaidInput.Text),
                Balance = Balance,
                Total = TotalQtyPurchased,
                SalesDetailsDate = Convert.ToDateTime(newSalesDate),
                //QuantityPuchased = Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantityBought.Text)
                //QuantityPuchased = quan
                //SalesDetailsDate = 

            };

            posDBcontext.GetSalesDetails.Add(salesDetails);
            posDBcontext.SaveChanges();


            var q = SubmitSalesButton.Content as Product;
            var s = posDBcontext.Sales.Where(a => a.QuantityPurchased == q.QuantityAvailableInStock);


            AmountPaidInput.Clear();
            AmountDueDisplay.Clear();


            SalesDatagrid.ItemsSource = null;
            SalesDatagrid.Items.Clear();



            //var s = posDBContext.GetSalesDetails.Where(c => c.SalesID == c.SalesID);
            //var DetailSales = posManager.Sales.Where(c=> c.)

            //posManager.CreateSales(s);



            //TotalQtyPurchased = posDBContext.Sales.Sum(c => c.QuantityPurchased);
            //posDBContext.Products.

        }
```

I tried to do this

```
var TotalQtyBought = posDBcontext.Sales.Where(c => c.Total == c.Total); 
var StockLevel = posDBcontext.Products.Where(c => c.ProductPrice == c.ProductPrice); 

foreach (var item in StockLevel) { var newStock = item - TotalQtyBought; }
```

I got this error

````
But I got this error cannot apply operands to type Product and iQueryable<sale> ```
````

Comment: The should be a table in the database that indicates the number of items in stock.  You need to find the table and column name a reduce stock quantity by number of items purchased.  Normally that is done in a stored procedure in database when you have a multi-user database and not in the client code.  So if two users are purchasing the same item at the same time a conflict doesn't occur where the quantity in database is not correct.

Comment: "I have been getting errors" - what errors? Please never post up on SO that you're getting an error, without saying WHAT error. This question seems a bit too broad to be a fit for the site rules; you're asking us to make design decisions for your app

Comment: I tried to do this  `  var TotalQtyBought = posDBcontext.Sales.Where(c => c.Total == c.Total);
            var StockLevel = posDBcontext.Products.Where(c => c.ProductPrice == c.ProductPrice);
            foreach (var item in StockLevel)
            {
                var newStock = item - TotalQtyBought;
            } `   But I got this error  "cannot apply operands to type Product and iQueryable<sale>"

Comment: @GertArnold I dont know what to do. I have used .ToList(); and .AsQueryable(). None is working

Comment: var TotalQtyBought = posDBcontext.Sales.Where(c => c.Total == c.Total) ?!?!?! Your where clause doesn't filter anything, it will always be true.  So you are pulling back all of the sales records and then calling it a totalqtybought.  records vs fields... think about it... You probably want to do a sum here.

Answer (score 0):

Your example around EF doesn't make any sense, so I'd recommend reading up on the basics of using EF and how to: read Entities, update Entities, and insert Entities.

Think of EF entities and queries like working with tables & SQL.

If you want to find a product, and update it:

```
// -- SQL --
UPDATE Product SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ProductId = 101;

// -- EF --
var product = context.Products.Single(x => x.ProductId == 101);
product.Quantity -= 1;
context.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to insert a new Sale record.

```
// -- SQL --
INSERT INTO Sales (ProductId, Total) 
SELECT ProductId, Price FROM Products WHERE ProductId = 101;

// -- EF --
var product = context.Products.Single(x => x.ProductId == 101);
var sale = new Sale { Product = product, Total = product.Price };
context.Sales.Add(sale);
context.SaveChanges();
```

So answering your question will be difficult until you understand the basics of how EF selects data, (`Where`, `Single`, `ToList`, etc.) how entities relate data with each other, and how you go about inserting vs. updating entities to create and update the related data tables.  Once you've got the gist of that then you should get a bit further and be able to rephrase your question with a better example of what you've tried, and what you want to accomplish.